# Merge Border Colors for a section tag using CSS

Tags: html, css, border

I created a centered slightly rotated section border. Also, I gave each side of the section different color. Here what my basic code looks like:

```css
body{
    background-color: #594451;
    color: #fff;
}

.boxed{
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    /* border: 3pc solid rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1); */
    border-left: solid rgba(127, 203, 170, 1) 3pc;
    border-right: solid rgba(186, 179, 173, 1) 3pc;
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 171, 238, 1) 3pc;
    border-top: solid rgba(229, 99, 57, 1) 3pc;
    height: 20pc;
    width: 20pc;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to Rahul's Lab</h1>
    <section class="boxed">
        <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
    </section>
```

Can I achieve border overlapped on each other? Is it possible by just using CSS or Do I have to create separate section/div for that? 
[HTML & CSS Design and build websites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKdtI.png)

Reference: Cover picture of HTML & CSS Design and build websites by Jon Duckett.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borders overlaping isn't possible…

… but, here is a solution to create your effect with CSS only, using:

- Multiple `linear-gradient`s to create the `background`
- `background-blend-mode` to mix the colors in the corners

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Updated snippet:**
*Using background shorthand syntax, like Temani did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50526694/5061000*

```css
.boxed {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5pc auto; /* Modified to better fit in tiny snippet */
  --border-pc: 10%; /* You could even use a CSS variable to store the width if you want to be able to modify it easily. Or the colors. Or both. */
  background:
    /* Shorthand syntax used below: image position/sizeX sizeY */
    linear-gradient(rgba(229, 099, 057, 1), rgba(229, 099, 057, 1)) top   /100% var(--border-pc), /* Orange with CSS var */
    linear-gradient(rgba(000, 171, 238, 1), rgba(000, 171, 238, 1)) bottom/100% var(--border-pc), /* Blue */
    linear-gradient(rgba(127, 203, 170, 1), rgba(127, 203, 170, 1)) left  /var(--border-pc) 100%, /* Green */
    linear-gradient(rgba(186, 179, 173, 1), rgba(186, 179, 173, 1)) right /var(--border-pc) 100%; /* Gray */
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 20pc;
  width: 20pc;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="boxed">
  <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
</section>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old style snippet:**
*Yep, it's working, but I prefer the first one!*

```css
.boxed {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5pc auto; /* Modified to better fit in tiny snippet */
  --border-pc: 10%; /* You could even use a CSS variable to store the width if you want to be able to modify it easily. Or the colors. Or both. */
  /* I tried to indent it to better see the code: */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to top, /* Blue */
      rgba(0, 171, 238, 1) 0%,
      rgba(0, 171, 238, 1) var(--border-pc), /* example use of the CSS var */
      transparent var(--border-pc) ),
    linear-gradient(to right, /* Green */
      rgba(127, 203, 170, 1) 0%,
      rgba(127, 203, 170, 1) 10%,
      transparent 10% ),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, /* Orange */
      rgba(229, 99, 57, 1) 0%,
      rgba(229, 99, 57, 1) 10%, 
      transparent 10% ),
    linear-gradient(to left, /* Gray */
      rgba(186, 179, 173, 1) 0%,
      rgba(186, 179, 173, 1) 10%,
      transparent 10% );
  background-blend-mode: multiply; /* Added to mix the colors */
  height: 20pc;
  width: 20pc;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="boxed">
  <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
</section>
```

(Note that if you don't use the `background-blend-mode` you can pick which gradients are overlapping the others by playing with their order!)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @TakitIsy, I wanted to achieve it using four colors only, Also appreciate extra tips on

Comment: @rahulkesharwani You must want to see the updated snippet, simplified using Temani's method!

Answer (score 3):

It is not really possible to overlap the borders, as they always meet at a certain angle in a div. It's still possible to create your effect by making separate blocks, though. The property `mix-blend-mode` allows for the overlay effect as provided by your image.

Keep in mind that `mix-blend-mode` doesn't have any support for [IE/Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode).

Here's how it can be done:

```css
body {
  margin: 30px
}

.block1 {
  background: rgba(127, 203, 170, 1);
}

.block2 {
  background: rgba(0, 171, 238, 1);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 20px 0;
  mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.block3 {
  background: rgba(186, 179, 173, 1);
  transform: translateY(140px);
  mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.block4 {
  background: rgba(229, 99, 57, 1);
  transform: translateY(30px) translateX(90px) rotate(90deg);
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.block {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1 block"></div>
<div class="block2 block"></div>
<div class="block3 block"></div>
<div class="block4 block"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I liked the idea of using single div block only, but would definitely look into mix-blend-mode.

Comment: 45 degrees isn't **always the case**. Borders meet at an angle proportional to their border-widths - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/aGgjGj

Comment: @Paulie_D, you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution with gradient and without the need of `mix-blend-mode`. The idea is to make each corner using a gradient so you can easily control the color and simulate the overlap:

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
  background:
    /*The 4 corners*/
    linear-gradient(#905c3f,#905c3f) top left/20px 20px,
    linear-gradient(#b04d32,#b04d32) top right/20px 20px,
    linear-gradient(#02a9ae,#02a9ae) bottom left/20px 20px,
    linear-gradient(#0085aa,#0085aa) bottom right/20px 20px,
    
    /*The 4 borders*/
    linear-gradient(#e6663a,#e6663a) top/100% 20px,
    linear-gradient(#01adf0,#01adf0) bottom/100% 20px,
    linear-gradient(#7fcaac,#7fcaac) left/20px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#bab1ae,#bab1ae) right/20px 100%;  
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   
   transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Hey Temani :) What is this syntax `position / 20px 20px` ? And why is it not working if doing it on `background-image`? You're always doing new things to me!

Comment: @TakitIsy it's a syntax for multiple background ;) .. for each one you specify the image [the gradient in this case with one color] and you specify the size and position at the same time. Then it's important to set everything as no-repeat or all of them will get repeated and it won't work

Comment: @TakitIsy background image allow you to set only the image [the gradient] so you cannot add position/size ... but here it's the shorthand version including image/size/position

Comment: It's not possible to do something like "#905c3f top left/20px 20px, […]" in your `background`?

Comment: @TakitIsy no :) all the trick is there, a color is not an image so you cannot apply size/position ... a color can only be used as the final layer [background-color] ... but if you specify a linear-gradient with same color, you will have YOUR color that you can adjust easily ;) .. so what I did is exactly like this, but with a valid syntax

Comment: @TemaniAfif I love your solution, the syntax is a lot easier than mine. You could remove the corners and add `background-blend-mode:multiply;` to fulfill all the needs of the OP (only one div, only 4 colors).

Comment: (Or if you prefer I'll do it in mine! :p)

Comment: @TakitIsy feel free to do it ;) but the main idea of my solution is to not use mix-blend-mode to avoid browser support issues. That's why I propsed a solution with only gradient that is more supported

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry for replying so late, I was moving out at that time, I just tried it now, It really an elegant solution, it works perfectly with other sections as well, and I am still learning, Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found how to do that is the following, there might be better options:

```css
body{
    background-color: #594451;
    color: #fff;
}

.boxed1, .boxed2, .boxed3, .boxed4 {
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    /* border: 3pc solid rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1); */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 20pc;
    width: 20pc;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
}

.boxed1 {
    border-top: solid rgba(229, 99, 57, 1) 3pc;
}

.boxed2 {
    border-right: solid rgba(186, 179, 173, 1) 3pc;
}

.boxed3 {
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 171, 238, 1) 3pc;
}

.boxed4 {
    border-left: solid rgba(127, 203, 170, 1) 3pc;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to Rahul's Lab</h1>
    <section class="boxed1">
        <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
    </section>
    <section class="boxed2">
        <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
    </section>
    <section class="boxed3">
        <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
    </section>
    <section class="boxed4">
        <!-- <p>This will contain the box properly</p> -->
    </section>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Inacio I was looking for merging the border only on corners, anyways Thanks for answering!!